# Hotmail and ActiveSync

Tags: activesync, hotmail

I'm working on an application which uses ActiveSync to sync data from Windows Live Hotmail. My problem is that Hotmail uses ActiveSync protocol version 2.5 and I can't find any documentation related to it! The latest version of the protocol documentation is easily available, but that doesn't help. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Since there is no "open" SDK/library available for ActiveSync (or am I wrong?), I'll have to work on it from scratch, and that's proving really difficult without the right protocol specification!

Also, is there any other way to sync all emails from Hotmail besides ActiveSync? For example, I want the contents of all folders `Sent Mail`, `Trash`, `Drafts` etc besides `Inbox`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Microsoft only opened the protocol docs from v.12.0 (Exchange 2007) onwards, but the majority of the "sync" parts of it should work the same for 2003/v2.5. If you look at this [comparison table](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/exchange-activesync-client-comparison-table.aspx), you'll see that 2.5 supports Direct Push and Sync for Email/Calendar/Contacts/etc, so it should work. I would suggest you try implementing the protocol based on the docs for 12.x and test it against Hotmail as you go.

Just be a good ActiveSync client and the server (Hotmail in your case) will move you along the sync workflow. That means calling OPTIONS to begin with, then trying a FolderSync, then watching the response to see if you need to Provision, etc. Once you start speaking WBXML to the server it will usually be very clear about what you need to do next to be successful.

As for the second part of your question: sure, you can sync any folder you want. You just need to specify which folder you're sync'ing with using the Collection ID within the Sync command request. [This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160228%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) shows how to sync a Calendar folder which happens to have an ID of 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I've been breaking my head with trial-and-error for sometime now! I've gotten through to the `FolderSync` stage... According to the protocol docs, I should then use `Sync` to get the contents of the folders. That just isn't working with Hotmail! Like I mentioned earlier, the same thing works seamlessly on an EAS installation as well as Gmail (all supporting versions >= 12.0).